# How to fade in div when its background is loaded with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, image, load

We have some divs off class 'divBG', we want each of them to fade in right after its background is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".divBG").hide(); //hide all cubes of class cubes
$(".divBG").each(function(){

    var id=this.id; //get cube id
    bg = $(this).css('background-image');    //get div bg url
    bg = bg.replace(/^url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '');     //change css url property: [url('url')] ---> [url] only

    if (bg) {       //if div has bg
        var a = new Image;  
        a.onload = function( ){ $('#'+id).fadeIn(1000)};        //fade in cube when image is loaded. 
        a.src = bg; //load image with given url
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
function loadImage(div, imageUrl)
{   
    var img = new Image();
    $(img).load(function () 
        {
            $(div).html(this).fadeIn(1000);
        }
    ).attr('src', imageUrl);
}

loadImage("#div1", "image.png");
```

This will load the image in a div and then fade it in. You can put them together in a container and put some text on it if you want to use it as background.